# How to authenticate JIRA with deployd, angularjs and jira-connector?

Tags: angularjs, jira, deployd

I am very new to JIRA and deployd.
I am having a problem with getting authentication from JIRA through deployd and angularjs.

I am using this npm service for JIRA connector 
https://github.com/floralvikings/jira-connector

in my angularjs code here is the dpd post method

```
dpd.jira.post($scope.jira, function (result, err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        };
        console.log(result, result.id);
    });
```

In this **$scope.jira**, I am sending the host and base64 for authentication as mentioned in this doc
https://github.com/floralvikings/jira-connector#basic-authentication-base64

And in my dpd post event i am using this function

```
const JiraClient = require('jira-connector');
const jira = new JiraClient( {
  host: this.url,
    basic_auth: {
      base64: this.hashKey
    }
  });
```

Now I want to make sure if this authentication is valid or not,
If it is valid then the post will be a success else it will through error message.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

*Please do not do any negative vote, as I am in serious trouble*

Comment: and what is your issue? what happens when you execute a simple GET request vs your Jira Instance after you authentictadd?

Comment: i want to check, the provided Jira authentication credential are correct or not. if correct then it will post else, return false